# Octave not recognizing python is installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, octave, symbolic-math

I am trying to install the symbolic package in octave, I have the package in the correct directory, which is my current directory in Octave, but when it tries to install the package it gives me an error saying it can't find python.  I'm using `octave version 4.0.0` and just installed `Python 2.7.10`. Here is my code attempting the install:

```
>> pkg install symbolic-2.2.1.tar.gz
configure: error: Failed to find Python
checking for python... no

pkg: error running the configure script for symbolic.
error: called from 'configure_make' in file C:\Octave\Octave- 4.0.0\share\octave\4.0.0\m\pkg\private\configure_make.m near line 79, column 9
```

In case it is relevant, Python is installed outside of the octave directory. If there is an easier way to get symbolic capabilities in octave please let me know.

Comment: python needs to be in your path. Can you start python by simply typing `python` at the command line (not at the Octave prompt)?

Comment: I am using windows, so I'm not exactly sure how to do that. I mean, if I try it from the windows command prompt it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: if not even the windows prompt know where to find python, you can't expect Octave to find it. You will need to read about configuring the windows PATH. I think there was an option when installing python that does it automatically. This is more of a [superuser](http://superuser.com/) question.

Answer (score 1):

First open the prompt and run 'python'. If the python console is not opened and the prompt says that this command is not recognized, you have my same problem and I was able to fix just adding python to the environment path.

To fix it:

1. Hold <kbd>Win</kbd> and press <kbd>Pause</kbd>.
2. Click Advanced System Settings.
3. Click Environment Variables.
4. Append `;C:\python27` to the `Path` variable.
5. Restart Command Prompt.