# Octave can't find JRE while I have installed JRE

Tags: octave

I have installed JRE successfully:

[image: Screenshor]

However, Octave keeps showing that it can't find JRE.

Comment: probably similar to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31142220/4183191

Comment: You need to provide more information. How did you install octave? How did you install java? Can you run java from the command prompt? Where does octave tell you it can’t find java, during install? When trying to run a function?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you installed right architecture(x86 or x64) of jre, it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Following https://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Octave-4-installer-doesn-t-detect-JRE-at-install-time-td4670684.html and: https://superuser.com/questions/1382158/on-windows-why-java-version-return-error-opening-registry-key-software-javas

1. run regedit.exe as Admin
2. change CurrentVersion in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\ to 12.0.2
3. create: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\12.0.2
4. set JavaHome in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\12.0.2\ to: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2
5. open cmd and type: java -version
6. in case of error type: where java
7. cmd will return folder or few; in explorer go to the one ending with \javapath for example C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
8. there should be files: java.exe javaw.exe and javaws.exe
9. if so delete them, reopen cmd and type java -version

Now it should display correct version without errors

10. In Octave type javachk jvm

if ans is empty java should be working now

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you presented, you have the JDK (development kit) installed, not the JRE (runtime environment). The required commands you need are there, but the operating system does not recognize this automatically. For that, you must include the 'java/bin' directory from the JDK in the PATH environment variable for your system. Next time you run Octave, it will locate and recognize the Java environment.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When writing an answer, you may want to explain why you think your answer is correct, as it may be the case it is not targeting exactly the same problem and the explanation may help to see why

Comment: Thanks, @bamishr. I edited my answer to address your suggestion.