# Octave is really slow and "not responding"

Tags: installation, octave, freeze

I installed Octave 5.2.0_1 on Windows 10 via the installer. The Octave GUI starts really slow (>20s). When I try moving the window or creating a new file, Octave freezes for several minutes.

things I tried:

- Looking at CPU and RAM usage, found no problem there
- restarting the PC
- reinstalling Octave, also deleting the folder "octave" in C:\CurrentUser.config\ before reinstalling
- downloading zip and starting from octave.vbs (same problem)
- Octave also doesn't find JRE, tried this:  [Octave can't find JRE while I have installed JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58815879/octave-cant-find-jre-while-i-have-installed-jre), but I can't find "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\"
- I think I already had Octave installed on this PC some time ago and it worked fine. But I'm not sure.

Comment: I have no idea how we can help. Maybe report to Octave instead. This is not a programming question

Comment: Ok sorry, I will do that

Comment: are you running the 64 bit or 32 bit version ? How much RAM do you have on that computer.

Comment: I'm running 64 bit with 8GB RAM